# Selectively neglected collection

Tags: wordplay, visual, combinatorics

**These mannequins are complete and ready for display.**

[image: four_complete_mannequins]

**These parts were found in a storage closet.  Create four additional mannequins by assembling the parts appropriately and designing a suitable outfit for each torso.**

[image: sixteen_mannequin_parts]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These mannequins all have something in common...

> Reading from one hand to the opposite foot yields an English word:
>  1. "cybernetic" and "underneath"
>  2. "devilishly" and "nihilistic"
>  3. "abominable" and "terminator"
>  4. "accurately" and "figurative"

So what we need to do to assemble the remaining mannequins is too...

> Find pairs of 10-letter words formed with the given pieces with the same middle four letters:
>  1. "barBERShop" and "cumBERSome"
>  2. "medDLESome" and "worDLESsly"
>  3. "impERATive" and "modERATely"
>  4. "inoRDINate" and "stuRDINess"

And as [tmpearce](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/26596/tmpearce) points out the comments,

> "All words in the title contain the same four-letter inner sequence 'lect'", which hints at the property of the mannequins.

Comment: Note also that rot13(Nyy jbeqf va gur gvgyr pbagnva gur fnzr sbhe-yrggre vaare frdhrapr "yrpg")

Comment: Usually I try to figure out how the title is relevant to a puzzle; this time I didn't even think about it - good catch!